# Next.js 13 overwriting css module problem

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

i have got a problem with overwriting css in my component while i want to pass a custom className to them.

i have got this component in `button.tsx`:

```
import { FC } from "react";
import styles from "./button.module.css";

const Button: FC<{ className?: string }> = ({ className = "" }) => {
  return (
    <button className={`${className} ${styles.button}`}>hello word</button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

and this style in `button.module.css`:

```
.button {
  background-color: green;
}
```

then i'm using it in my `page.tsx` file like this:

```
import { FC } from 'react';
import styles from "./home.module.css";
import Button from "./button";

const Home: FC = () => {
  return (
    <main>
      <Button className={styles.customButton} />
    </main>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

with this style in `home.module.css`:

```
.customButton {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

now when i run the project the color of button is green and the `customeButton` class doesn't overwrite. but when i add `"use client";` to the top of `button.tsx`, it will overwrite.
how can i overwrite my `customButton` class without adding `"use client";`?

Answer (score 1):

There's many different factors that go into the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of a style, and though it may not be clear why `button` is getting treated preferentially to `customButton`, there are a couple ways to fix it.

**Any override classes can be appended with an [`!important`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/important) property to make sure they take priority.**

*Example*:

```
.customButton {
  background-color: purple !important;
}
```

Using this can get out of hand pretty quickly, however, so a cleaner solution for your use case is **to conditionally render either a provided `className` prop if it exists, or the default otherwise**. This avoids any conflation between the two conflicting classes to begin with. We'll use a [ternary statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator) for this.

*Example*:

```
// NOTE: no className default in parameters; will be undefined if none provided
const Button: FC<{ className?: string }> = ({ className }) => {
  return (
    // if className exists, render that. else, styles.button will act as a default
    <button className={className ? className : styles.button}>hello world</button>
  );
};
```